# Jupyter Notebook - Customize Style/Themes

Tags: jupyter-notebook, themes, jupyter-lab

I am currently using **dunovank/jupyter-themes** to style my notebook. I would like to change the comment color however, but it does not seem like jupyter-themes has this customizability.

Are there any alternatives to Jupyter-themes, or other possible ways of editing an existing themes?

Comment: Work around solution -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70489744/3761924