# How to increase comments contrast in jupyter notebook dark themes?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, comments, high-contrast, dark-theme

How do I make comments contrast more with the dark background?

I am curious about customizing dark themes in jupyter notebooks. I installed jupyter themes with the jupyter-themes package:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterthemes
```

The available themes seem to make the comments too light. i.e. they don't contrast enough.
I tried various themes:

```
jt -t chesterish
```

Soft blueish Headings and bolds but comments almost not visible

```
jt -t monokai -m 200
```

markdown is in bright green (i.e. headings, etc). But comments are some dark brownish hue making them almost invisible.

```
jt -t onedork # contrast too low
```

Onedork has even less contrast for all text (except numerical values and commands)
[![onedork has low contrast text][1]][1]

I want to make it like a bright grey, like the here in the stackoverflow dark theme?

This question was also asked in [Jupyter Notebook - Customize Style/Themes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70159852/3761924) but no answers yet
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/95yYJ.png

Answer (score 1):

If you use MS Edge, a work around that impacts all websites, not just jupyter notebooks, is a browser extension called Dark Reader.
https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/dark-reader/ifoakfbpdcdoeenechcleahebpibofpc

Before installing it... I reset the jt dark themes and restarted jupyter notebooks

```
jt -r
jupyter notebook &
```

[image: Contrast in Jupyter Notebooks with Dark Reader extension]

Comment: Not happy that I had to make it a browser extension. I plan on disabling it when not using jupyter notebooks.

Comment: Unfortunately, it removed the colors, but at least the contrast is high enough. I will probably revert back to without the extension... because the colors made things easier to see. I will just have to live with the whiteish background.